# Permission issue. Access denied

Tags: 2013, permissions

I have a user in a SharePoint created group which has 'limited' permissions on a site, but contribute permissions on a list in that site. When the user tries to save an item he receives the error:

> Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or
>   access this resource.

Comment: Turns out the issue was related to the `Override List Behaviors` permission. The list had the `Create items and edit items that were created by the user ` restriction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was related to the Override List Behaviors permission. The list had the Create items and edit items that were created by the user restriction.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the action, list permissions are dependent on site level permissions.  In order to save a list item, the user has to at least have the View Pages, View Items, and Open permissions at the site level.  So the group that user is a part of would need to have those granted.

This site has the full dependency listings:

[Understanding SharePoint permissions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Understanding-permission-levels-87ecbb0e-6550-491a-8826-c075e4859848#__toc344968767)